# crossdomain.xml location when Tomcat is running in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, tomcat, crossdomain.xml

I need to use a crossdomain.xml file to access my WebApp from a dev sandbox.
I gather from other SO posts that it should be accessible at `http://localhost:8080/crossdomain.xml` , hence in tomcat ROOT webapp.
**Where the heck is that ROOT directory when running Tomcat in Eclipse?**

**Edit**: Tomcat is using a Runtime Environment named "Apache Tomcat v6.0" which is using a "Tomcat installation directory" set to "D:\dev\apache-tomcat-6.0.33"
I tried to drop crossdomain.xml in "D:\dev\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\webapps\ROOT" but I still get a 404 trying to access `http://localhost:8080/crossdomain.xml` from a browser. In fact, anything in that ROOT directory is accessible.

**Edit 2**: In the server launch configuration, there is an "Arguments" tab listing the following `-Dcatalina.base="D:\dev\workspaces\project\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1" -Dcatalina.home="D:\dev\apache-tomcat-6.0.33" -Dwtp.deploy="D:\dev\workspaces\project\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="D:\dev\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\endorsed"`
Hence, I pasted the crossdomain.xml into `D:\dev\workspaces\project\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\ROOT` and ... it worked. Seriously.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I no Java expert; but I don't understand what "Running Tomcat in Eclipse means". Usually my server software and my IDE are completely separate from each other [even when on the same machine for development purposes]

Comment: Eclipse can run Tomcat as a plugin. This is pretty cool to debug WebApps on the fly.

Comment: Interesting.  If I read your "Edit 2" correctly; then you have solved the problem.  I would recommend you answer your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per edit #2
In server launch configuration, there is an "Arguments" tab listing the following VM Arguments
`-Dcatalina.base="D:\dev\workspaces\project\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1" -Dcatalina.home="D:\dev\apache-tomcat-6.0.33" -Dwtp.deploy="D:\dev\workspaces\project\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="D:\dev\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\endorsed"`
Hence, I pasted the crossdomain.xml into `D:\dev\workspaces\project\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\ROOT`